# Is there a way to do this in Rails without mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

Members create votes that both belong to them and to another model, Issues. Currently I'm doing this with a hidden form and passing the appropriate parameters. Here's the code on the issues index view:

```
<%= form_for(@vote) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "issue_id", :value => issue.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "member_id", :value => session[:member_id] %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "type", :value => :Upvote %>
    <%= f.label issue.upvotes_count(issue.id) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Up", :class => 'up-vote' %>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't seem ideal as it leaves issue_id and member_id open to mass assignment. Is there a better way to do this with a button_to tag or something?

Here's the controller code:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  #GET
  def new
    @vote = Vote.new
  end

  # POST
  def create
    @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])
    @vote.member_id = current_member

    if @vote.save
        redirect_to issues_path
    else
        redirect_to issues_path, notice: "you must be logged in to vote"
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController

  # GET
  def index
    @issues = Issue.find(:all)
    @vote = Vote.new
  end

  # GET
  def show
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end 

  end

end
```

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you also show your controller code. Like timpone is saying below: it's nonsense to pass the `session[:member_id]` like this. Just use `current_user` in your controller. Not related to your question, but `issue.upvotes_count(issue.id)` is very strange. Why pass the `id` to a instance method if you already have an instance?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (the count functions). I refactored the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scope in the controller:

```
@issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])
@vote = @issue.votes.new(params[:vote])
@vote.save
```

and do not pass member_id and issue_id to hidden fields.

If you have proper nested RESTful routes you should be able to get params[:issue_id] directly.

Answer (score 1):

If `issue` and `member_id` are available before you `vote.save!` in the controller, you can set them manually there.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you get values like `member_id` from `current_user` in the controller rather than passing it via form parameters. How you have it currently does expose you to mass-assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Do members have to login before voting? If so, then you don't need to include member_id as a hidden field because you can grab current_user in the controller and this will provide good protection since there wouldn't be any advantage for a member to hack issue_id or type.